# Show that $z=a+ib$ with $a+b\equiv0 \pmod 2$ implies $z=c-d + i(c+d)$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider $z=a+ib\; ,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $a+b\equiv0 \pmod 2$. I want to show that this implies that I can write $z$ on the form $z=c-d + i(c+d)$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$.

How do I do that?

I know $a+b\equiv0 \pmod 2 \Leftrightarrow a+b=2c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$.
But I don't think that's sufficient information to show it.
I could write
$$a=c-d\; \text{for some}\; d\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$b=c+k\; \text{for some}\; k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

But how do I show that $k=d$ given the conditions.

Edit:
Nevermind, I got it.

Comment: $c-d=a$, $c+d=b$ so that $2c=a+b=2m$ and so $c=m$. then use $c-d=a$ to work out $d$ in terms of $a$ and $m$

Comment: But don't you assume what I want to prove. I can't assume that I can write $a=c-d$ and $b=c+d$.

Comment: @JustWandering It's just that I could say that $a+b=2c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$. And I could write $a=c-d$ for some $d\in\mathbb{Z}$. And I could also write $b=c+k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But how do I show that $k$ has to $k=d$

Comment: Okay, never mind. I'm fucking stupid :D